# r ggplot how to adjust the column width of bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I need to figure out how to adjust the width of a plot for based on a a specific variable without having the change the `scales = "free"` parameter of `facet_wrap` function. I tried using the a `case_when` that adjusts the width of the bar based on the variable, but I get an error.[image]

below is reproducible example that shows the issue I'm having.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

data.frame(date = rep(seq.Date(Sys.Date()
                       , by = "day", length.out = 10), 3)
,Time = rep(c("AM","PM"), each = 30)
,office = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2)
,n = sample(c(50:100),60, replace = TRUE)) %>%
add_row(date = Sys.Date(), Time = "AM", office = "Z", n = 80) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n, group = office)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack'
         ,width = .7, show.legend = FALSE, alpha =.75) +
facet_wrap(vars(office, Time), ncol = 2, labeller = "label_both",
           scales = "free")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specifically require use of `facet_wrap()`, you should use `facet_grid()`, which contains a very useful argument: `space`.  Whereas `scales` allows the scale of each plot to resize according to "empty" data, `space` sort of does the same thing, but allows you to keep the same overall width of the bar constant.

```
data.frame(date = rep(seq.Date(Sys.Date()
                               , by = "day", length.out = 10), 3)
           ,Time = rep(c("AM","PM"), each = 30)
           ,office = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2)
           ,n = sample(c(50:100),60, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  add_row(date = Sys.Date(), Time = "AM", office = "Z", n = 80) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n, group = office)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack'
           ,width = .7, show.legend = FALSE, alpha =.75) +
  facet_grid(office ~ Time, labeller = "label_both",
             scales = "free", space='free')
```

[image]

I do wish `facet_wrap()` had `space` as an argument, but alas, that is not the case at this time.  If you need to have the facets all in one row or column, you can use `facet_row()` or `facet_col()` from the `ggforce` package.  They allow the use of the `space` argument, but you are limited to only one row or column (not wrapping).